# How to prepare a sql Query with ORDER BY and LIMIT 1 in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to prepare this query for Oracle 11g database, but it is not compatible with this version:

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTS WHERE UPPER(NOMBRE) LIKE ? ORDER BY NUM DESC LIMIT 1;
```

With ORDER BY NUM DESC LIMIT 1, I only want the first result with the maximum "NUM"

Any alternative to do this in Oracle 11g?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NUM DESC) rn
    FROM CLIENTS c
    WHERE UPPER(NOMBRE) LIKE ?
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is use `rownum` pseudo column

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM clients 
    WHERE UPPER(nombre) LIKE ? 
    ORDER BY num DESC
)
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Comment: @zealous `rownum` is a pseudo column created by oracle, FYI you could search using google

Comment: Or simply read the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROWNUM-Pseudocolumn.html#GUID-2E40EC12-3FCF-4A4F-B5F2-6BC669021726